# Python Pandas Replace String in Column within For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to concatnate all files in the file list
 `file_list`:

`result = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).set_index(['a', 'b', 'c']) for f in file_list])`

The challenge is that, I would like to replace string `'xyz'` with nothing in `column[b]` before `set_index`. How can I achieve this in the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need `replace` with nested `dict`:

```
dfs=[pd.read_csv(f).replace({'b':{'xyz':''}}).set_index(['a', 'b', 'c']) for f in file_list]
result = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Or if `xyz` strings are not in columns `a` and `c` is possible create `MultiIndex` and then replace all `xyz`:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, index_col=['a','b','c']).rename({'xyz':''}) for f in file_list]
result = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Last if nothing is `NaN` only use `{'xyz':np.nan}` instead `{'xyz':''}`

EDIT by comment:

For replace by `regex`:

```
dfs= [pd.read_csv(f).replace({'b':{'xyz*':''}}, regex=True).set_index(['a', 'b', 'c']) for f in file_list]
result = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: Just to add, I used regular expression `dfs=[pd.read_csv(f).replace({'b':{'xyz*':''}}, regex=True)`.

Comment: I add it to answer too.